# Is there any alternative for `qiskit.initialize` in aws braket for running circuit on `Ionq Device`?

Tags: qiskit, amazon-braket, ionq

I'm trying to run a quantum circuit created in Qiskit, on Ionq Device using `qiskit_braket_provider`. Getting some error while transpiling the circuit because circuit contains a `qiskit.initialize` instruction. Is there any alternative for `initialize` function in aws braket? Any other way out of this problem?

This problem can be recreated as:

**Code:**

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
st = random_statevector(2)
qc.initialize(st, 0)
qc.x(1)
tqc = transpile(qc,backend = ionq)
```

**Error:**

````
TranspilerError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [66], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 tqc = transpile(qc,backend = ionq)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py:341, in transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, inst_map, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method, translation_method, scheduling_method, instruction_durations, dt, approximation_degree, timing_constraints, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, callback, output_name, unitary_synthesis_method, unitary_synthesis_plugin_config, target)
    338     for circuit, unique_args in zip(circuits, unique_transpile_args):
    339         transpile_config, pass_manager = _combine_args(shared_args, unique_args)
    340         output_circuits.append(
--> 341             _serial_transpile_circuit(
    342                 circuit,
    343                 pass_manager,
    344                 transpile_config["callback"],
    345                 transpile_config["output_name"],
    346                 transpile_config["backend_num_qubits"],
    347                 transpile_config["faulty_qubits_map"],
    348                 transpile_config["pass_manager_config"].backend_properties,
    349             )
    350         )
    351     circuits = output_circuits
    352 end_time = time()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py:434, in _serial_transpile_circuit(circuit, pass_manager, callback, output_name, num_qubits, faulty_qubits_map, backend_prop)
    425 def _serial_transpile_circuit(
    426     circuit,
    427     pass_manager,
   (...)
    432     backend_prop=None,
    433 ):
--> 434     result = pass_manager.run(circuit, callback=callback, output_name=output_name)
    435     if faulty_qubits_map:
    436         return _remap_circuit_faulty_backend(
    437             result,
    438             num_qubits,
    439             backend_prop,
    440             faulty_qubits_map,
    441         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:507, in StagedPassManager.run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    500 def run(
    501     self,
    502     circuits: Union[QuantumCircuit, List[QuantumCircuit]],
    503     output_name: str = None,
    504     callback: Callable = None,
    505 ) -> Union[QuantumCircuit, List[QuantumCircuit]]:
    506     self._update_passmanager()
--> 507     return super().run(circuits, output_name, callback)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:224, in PassManager.run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    222     return circuits
    223 if isinstance(circuits, QuantumCircuit):
--> 224     return self._run_single_circuit(circuits, output_name, callback)
    225 if len(circuits) == 1:
    226     return self._run_single_circuit(circuits[0], output_name, callback)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:279, in PassManager._run_single_circuit(self, circuit, output_name, callback)
    267 """Run all the passes on a ``circuit``.
    268 
    269 Args:
   (...)
    276     The transformed circuit.
    277 """
    278 running_passmanager = self._create_running_passmanager()
--> 279 result = running_passmanager.run(circuit, output_name=output_name, callback=callback)
    280 self.property_set = running_passmanager.property_set
    281 return result

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:124, in RunningPassManager.run(***failed resolving arguments***)
    122 for passset in self.working_list:
    123     for pass_ in passset:
--> 124         dag = self._do_pass(pass_, dag, passset.options)
    126 circuit = dag_to_circuit(dag)
    127 if output_name:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:167, in RunningPassManager._do_pass(self, pass_, dag, options)
    165 # Run the pass itself, if not already run
    166 if pass_ not in self.valid_passes:
--> 167     dag = self._run_this_pass(pass_, dag)
    169     # update the valid_passes property
    170     self._update_valid_passes(pass_)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:196, in RunningPassManager._run_this_pass(self, pass_, dag)
    193 if pass_.is_transformation_pass:
    194     # Measure time if we have a callback or logging set
    195     start_time = time()
--> 196     new_dag = pass_.run(dag)
    197     end_time = time()
    198     run_time = end_time - start_time

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passes/basis/basis_translator.py:184, in BasisTranslator.run(self, dag)
    179 logger.info(
    180     "Basis translation path search completed in %.3fs.", search_end_time - search_start_time
    181 )
    183 if basis_transforms is None:
--> 184     raise TranspilerError(
    185         "Unable to map source basis {} to target basis {} "
    186         "over library {}.".format(source_basis, target_basis, self._equiv_lib)
    187     )
    189 # Compose found path into a set of instruction substitution rules.
    191 compose_start_time = time.time()

TranspilerError: "Unable to map source basis {('reset', 1), ('x', 1), ('rz', 1), ('ry', 1)} to target basis {'h', 'rzz', 's', 'sdg', 'tdg', 'rz', 'swap', 'barrier', 'cx', 'x', 'id', 'z', 'sx', 'sxdg', 'y', 'measure', 't', 'rxx', 'rx', 'ryy', 'snapshot', 'ry'} over library <qiskit.circuit.equivalence.EquivalenceLibrary object at 0x7f0900dd5ea0>."
```
````

Answer (score 2):

It seems the target device does not support resets. Since the initialization is the first instruction, you could use the `state_preparation` method *if* you are sure that the qubits are initialized in the $|0\rangle$ state.

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
st = random_statevector(2)
qc.prepare_state(st, 0)
qc.x(1)
tqc = transpile(qc, backend=ionq)
```

Comment: Thanks! `state_preparation` worked.